# mongodb-es6 promise not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am playing around mongodb-es6-master, in which it was written that mongoClient.connect() returns a promise, but i am not able to invoke the 'then' function on that promise. 
i have a file named index.js 
which i am invoking with node version 5.0.

following is the code snippet. Am i missing anything?

```
  
    'use strict'
    var co = require('co');
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb-es6').MongoClient;
    co(function* (){
    let client = yield new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/test",            {}).connect();

    var collectionP = yield client.then((value) => {
    //some code
    //    console throws  [TypeError]client.then in not a function
```

Comment: I suspect `client` is not actually a promise, but the client, hence the error. Suggest `var collectionP = yield client.someClientMethod(/* ... */);` might work.

Comment: connect() returns a promise, which would mean `client = yield ... connect()` results in client being the resolved value of the promise, not the promise itself

Comment: ...meaning  `client.then(/*...*/)` will throw an error - which is observed.